# Using Google Vision API with ARCore in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, object-detection, arcore, google-vision

I'm looking to build an app that detects certain objects and then overlays something using ARCore.  Is it possible to use Google's Vision API for real-time detection of objects? If not, is there another library that I could use that has object detection, landmark detection, and/or OCR?

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Did you find anything about this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732443/ar-core-to-measure-distance-between-two-real-objects - Here is my question