# AR Core to measure distance between two real objects

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am trying to detect the distance between two physical objects and if the distance is suitable between them , I want to place my AR object in between it. Can someone please help me in this? Or if this is possible through AR or not ?

Right now I am only able to measure distance between two AR Objects placed on the horizontal plane.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to measure distance using ARCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982196/how-to-measure-distance-using-arcore)

Comment: You need to use Depth API for this.